# Facebook API: Calls from backend server. Is my project feasible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My plan is to develop an application which creates user recommendations based on the user´s Facebook data (age, likes,...).

In this [Figure](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#authClientServer) (sry, i am not allow to post images directly) you can see the flow of the application. Is this the configuration "[Login on Client, API Calls from Server](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#authClientServer)" from the Facebook Documentation?

I am not sure because the *Recommendation Server*, which calls the Graph API, is not the same as the *Web Server*. Additionally, in the documentation it is mentioned that the Client forwards the API calls to the server. However, in my case the *Web Application (Client + Server)* does not know which API calls the *Recommendation Server* makes.

Is my project feasible? If not, how do I have to adapt my plan?

Comment: I think you're trying to ask that if you do the API call from a different server & show the result on different? I don't think why it should be feasible. Now it also will depend on your Application Flow like I assume that your `recommendation server` will already have the data from FB & then will save the recommendations to a DB & then you will show that too the User. This would be feasible.

Comment: Exactly! My question is, if it is possible to do the login on the web server, transfer the access token to the recommendation server, and do the API call from from there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yeah sure it works that way too.

Comment: See "Tokens are Portable" in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#authClientServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem here if I understood correctly. Have one web server to the OAuth login, exchange the short-lived Access Token for a long-lived one, and store the Access Token somewhere in a (NoSQL or SQL) database such as Redis, MongoDB or MySQL where both web server and recommendation server have access to.

Then, the web server needs to trigger the recommendation server to do the calls he needs after the Access Token has been stored.